# SQL/TypeORM - How do you represent the "many" part of a one-to-many relation as multiple tables?

Tags: sql, node.js, database, typescript, typeorm

Agnostic of any storage details, imagine I have a domain object that would look like this in Typescript.

```
interface Cow {
  id: string;
  farmer_id: string;
  num_spots: number;
}

interface Pig {
  id: string;
  farmer_id: string;
  oink_decibals: number;
}

type Animal = Cow | Pig;

interface Farmer {
  id: string;
  animal: Animal[];
}
```

So `Animal` is a discriminated union type, where each animal has unique properties from others (`num_spots` vs `oink_decibals`).

The way I'm thinking of modeling this in SQLite is as 3 tables

| user | cow | pig |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id |
|  | num_spots | oink_decibals |
|  | user_id | user_id |

So Farmer -> Animal looks like a One-To-Many relationship to me, but the "Many" part is a discriminated union type, spread out across multiple tables. I'm not sure if modeling each type in the union as its own separate table is the best approach, and if it is, I'm not sure how to represent that relation in an ORM (in my case TypeORM)

```
@Entity()
class Farmer {
  @OneToMany(???)
  animals: ????;
}
```

I know I could just have separate fields for each sport

```
@Entity()
class Farmer {
  @OneToMany(() => Cow)
  cows: Cow[];

  @OneToMany(() => Pig)
  pigs: Pig[];
}
```

but I'm expecting the number of animals to grow as the app grows and evolves. I don't want my Farmer model to be flooded with tons of fields for each animal.

So I guess I have two parts to the question

1. Is this an appropriate way to model this kind of relation?
2. In TypeORM, how would I represent this relationship in an Entity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeorm-polymorphic` package:

```ts
@Entity()
export class Farmer implements PolymorphicChildInterface {
  @PolymorphicParent(() => [Cow, Pig])
  animal: Cow | Pig;

  @Column()
  entityId: number;

  @Column()
  entityType: string;
}
```

[Link](https://github.com/bashleigh/typeorm-polymorphic)